# do work in background when the condition is true

Tags: android

i want to  do work (in background) and do other operations in background
when a text field is changing 
i put a text view and i used on text change listener 
and inside it i tried calling runnable

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            handler.postDelayed(runreco,0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
  private Runnable runreco = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      calculate();
    }

};
```

but it is creating thread every time i call it and causes troubles
i want a good way to start some work in background  just when i need (resuming the same thread when i need)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) will help you

Answer (score 0):

why u just don't use your function inisede listener

```
onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
```

if u want create to this thread i recomend do it in other file write new class and new class of controller.
Class with thread will do what you want to do and controller will fire thread and stop thread
but i thing simple do thing in event will be enough